# Is there an easy GUI-based way to build graphs in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

Is there a GUI-builder for neo4j? I want to be able to quickly add new nodes, set labels, set properties and relationships all in a gui-environment by clicking on nodes in a visualisation. I have searched, but have found nothing. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the Neo4j browser: http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/ ? The Cypher query language is used for adding nodes, setting labels, etc. so it's not quite what you are describing but may be a good place to start.

Comment: @WilliamLyon the question is mainly about directly editing the graph on the graph, so I don't think neo4j browser is a valid option

Answer (score 25, accepted):

@Zuriar

Two years after your original post :) but nevertheless ..

Now there is also Graphileon InterActor (http://www.graphileon.com) , an enhanced user-interface for Neo4j. Multi-panel, create / update nodes and relations without writing a single line of code.

**UPDATE August 15th, 2018**

We have replaced the Sandbox and Community Edition by the Personal Edition. This version is free as well, and is distributed as a desktop app for MacOS, Windows and Linux. For more info, visit our [blog](https://graphileon.com/graphileon-personal-edition/).

**UPDATE June 22th, 2020**

We released version 2.7.0 of the Personal Edition, which supports Neo4j 4.0. For release notes , go here https://docs.graphileon.com/graphileon/Release_notes.html

**UPDATE Aug 8th, 2022**

Graphileon is now also available as a fully managed Cloud Service. Read more about it here https://graphileon.com/graphileon-cloud-has-arrived/

Disclosure : I work for Graphileon

Comment: the sandbox is invalid now.

Comment: @LukAron the text says that it was replaced by the PE. To avoid confusion, I removed the mention  of sandbox. Thanks for notifying us.

Comment: https://github.com/stefanak-michal/cyphergui

Answer (score 12):

Just lost a week trying to find a suitable tool for Neo4J.   It has somehow gotten more difficult.   My experience updated from the last post here (2015):

Gephi:
2015:  Supported Neo4j
2017:  Doesn't support Neo4j

Linxurious:
2015:  Free
2017:  Discontinued and doesn't list the price

Neoclipse:
2017:  No updates since 2014.  Doesn't work with the current version of Neo4J.

Structr:
Looks promising, but requires a lot of Java knowledge just to get it running.  Have lost days on this and still have not successfully installed.

It does not look good for Neo4J tools.   It was actually much better 2 years ago.

Comment: Thanks so much for the information on the current status of those options(not anymore).       I guess i will try my best to make one then, but it takes time

Answer (score 8):

There are at least 3 GUI tools for neo4j that allow editing:

- [neoclipse](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neoclipse/wiki)
- [Gephi](http://gephi.github.io/)
- [linkurious](http://linkurio.us/)

`neoclipse` and `Gephi` are open source and free. `linkurous` has a free open-source community edition.

Comment: Thanks, neoclipse looks like the last update to the code was Oct 2012 and it needs Java 6. Is there a later version I am missing?

Comment: Actually, [the last neoclipse commit](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neoclipse/commits/master) was less than a year ago, and it should support at least neo4j 2.1.4, according to one of the last commit messages.

Comment: You are correct, my bad. I have tried both v1.8 and v.1.9.5 -- v1.8 will run with Java-8, v1.9.5 requires Java 6. Bizarre  -however, although v1.8 will launch on Mac Yosemite it then won't connect to DB because update path is not supported - I guess my version of Neo is too new...

Comment: according to the answer by [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42910609/10189759)mypitboss .  They shouldn't be easy to use anymore I guess.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Neo4j's new bloom product would be suitable.
neo4j.com/bloom

Comment: note: It needs a license, and can be launched only within neo4j desktop currently