# GUI for building JanusGraph DB

Tags: graph-databases, janusgraph, graphileon

I am exploring JanusGraph DBs and require visual editing, like MySQL workbench.

I found some [visual editors for Neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32462505/is-there-an-easy-gui-based-way-to-build-graphs-in-neo4j). Are there any visual editors for JanusGraph as well? or can those tools be used with JanusGraph?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Per [JanusGraph's `README`](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/#visualization):

> To visualize graphs stored in JanusGraph, you can use any of the
> following tools:
>
> - [AWS Graph Notebook](https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook) - Open source
> - [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/)
> - [Gephi](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gephi-plugin)
>   plugin for Apache TinkerPop
> - [Graphexp](https://github.com/bricaud/graphexp)
> - [Graph Explorer](https://github.com/invanalabs/graph-explorer)
> - [KeyLines by Cambridge Intelligence](https://cambridge-intelligence.com/visualizing-janusgraph-new-titandb-fork/)
> - [Linkurious](https://doc.linkurio.us/ogma/latest/tutorials/janusgraph/)

Of these, at least Cytoscape and Graphexp also support visual graph editing.

Comment: I was not able to figure out how to use Gephi with JanusGraph; Linkurious seems promising but is not free.

Comment: @JamesWatkins — take a look at other options on https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/#visualization such as Cytoscape or GraphExp.

Comment: @JamesWatkins I had the same problem: Gephi works as a server, and gremlin comes to be the client. So, I had to start Gephi on windows, as per http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gephi-plugin , check firewall on both sides (mandatory!), start gremin on Linux, and follow the instructions there. When issueing ":remote connect tinkerpop.gephi", it says "...localhost...", so I just added ":remote config host 192.168.1.15", the windows-gephi-server IP.

Comment: Sir . the quesiton requires editing, but your answer is mentioning  "visualize" only.  Or actually the five tools provided are all able to edit graph?

Comment: @LukAron – thanks, good point! I've added a clarification about at least two of the visualization tools that support editing (I couldn't easily find a page for the others that say that they also support editing; they may or may not).

Comment: @MishaBrukman   oh! sorry that I miss the last sentence! now I saw it!  thanks so much for your answer!   I have spent tons of time finding tools like this to edit neo4j also, and I found that graphileon is exactly what I want.