# Any graphical interface of JanusGraph Gremlin Query

Tags: gremlin, titan, janusgraph

Currently, I'm executing my gremlin query via apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console - this is command interface. I'm looking for some graphical interface where I can pass all my attributes and relation - which should from a gremlin query and retrieve the data in a graphical format. Is there any opensource tool which I can use it for my use case. 
Please note we are using Janusgraph and our data source is Hbase.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GUI for building JanusGraph DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47254804/gui-for-building-janusgraph-db)

Answer (score 1):

I used [Graphexp](https://github.com/bricaud/graphexp) for visualization when i was working on Janusgraph. It is very lightweight, supports gremlin query execution as well as a nice visualization.

You don't need any third party dependecy to run it. Just a HTML file that you can open in browser.

It is not very advance and also has some issues here and there but it gets the job done.

Here is screenshot of the graph view my data:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Graphexp does not work very well in my experience, I recommend this project instead: https://github.com/prabushitha/gremlin-visualizer

[image]