# Can you edit node/relationship from UI level in neo4j browser?

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible to edit nodes from GUI level in neo4j browser?
I want to make MATCH query which returns some nodes and then edit them using UI. Just like you can do it in many SQL databases clients, where you SELECT some data, edit some rows by hand and commit changes to database.

Comment: There is a list of options mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32462505/is-there-an-easy-gui-based-way-to-build-graphs-in-neo4j

Answer (score 3):

Neo4j Browser doesn't have an option to edit the graph from the UI, but [Neo4j Bloom](https://neo4j.com/docs/bloom-user-guide/current/) does - [Edit graph data](https://neo4j.com/docs/bloom-user-guide/current/bloom-tutorial/edit-graph-data/)

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is a WYSIWYG type experience, which some RDBMS GUIs offer, but is usually not the most efficient nor safe way of updating your data.

If you want to edit the data in your database, you would have to use Cypher `CREATE` or `UPDATE` statements.

https://neo4j.com/developer/cypher/updating/